# PHPUnit calling same method twice with willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls results in empty data

Tags: php, phpunit

**Problem:** How to test same method (**getNextUniqueBunch**) with different results?

```
function exampleQuestion() {
  $rows = [];
  $rowsAgain = [];

  while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextUniqueBunch()) {
            $rows[] = $bunch;
  }

  //Some changes done and now getNextUniqueBunch will return a different result

  while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextUniqueBunch()) {
            $rowsAgain[] = $bunch;
  }
}
```

**Solution 1**:

```
public function importDataProvider(): array
{
    return [
        [
            [
                '_email' => 'jondoe@example.com',
                '_website' => 'base',
                '_store'=> 'admin',
                '_entity_id' => 'abc'
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                '_email' => 'jondoe@example.com',
                '_store' => 'admin',
                '_entity_id' => 'abc'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}

   /**
     * @dataProvider importDataProvider
     * @return void
     */
    public function testImportData($data)
    {
        $this->dataSourceModel->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getNextUniqueBunch')
            ->withConsecutive([], [])
            ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls([$data], [$data]);
       $mockClassObj->exampleQuestion(); 
    }
```

In this solution calling getNextUniqueBunch the first time will return an array but on the second getNextUniqueBunch call it returns an empty array

**Solution 2**:
It works for the second getNextUniqueBunch call if we change the code to

```
$this->dataSourceModel->expects($this->at(3))
            ->method('getNextUniqueBunch')
            ->withConsecutive([], [])
            ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls([$data], [$data]);
```

In this case, we are using deprecated **$this->at(3)** but it works and returns data for the second getNextUniqueBunch call

What will be the right way to achieve- same method calling with different results? I searched and investigated a lot but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

we need to add `null` in order to jump into the next same method while loop for example

```
$this->dataSourceModel->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getNextUniqueBunch')
            ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
                ['_email' => 'jondoe@example.com'],
                ['_website' => 'base'],
                ['_store'=> 'admin'],
                ['_entity_id' => 'abc'],
                null,
                ['_email' => 'jondoe@example.com'],
                ['_store' => 'admin'],
                ['_entity_id' => 'abc']
            );
```